# How I can add a string to each line of bash command returning multiple lines e.g. du or ls -l

Tags: bash, shell-script

I want to create a contents file for some directories, which shall be stored in several `tar` archives. I use

```
du --all currentdir >> contents.list
```

for that.

I want to append the name of the `tar` archive to each line of `du` output before I write it to file. I assume I can do it in this way:

```
du --all currentdir | while read  i; do echo "$i mytar" >> contents.list ; done
```

I suspect that a more simple solution exists for this, but I'm a bash scripting novice.

Comment: "I want to add the name of the tar archive to each line of du output ": what tar archive?

Comment: I need to archive about 10 TB of scientific data. I want to avoid a huge archive and try to divide it into smaller packages of e.g. 500 GB each. The subfolders fulfil this condition. So I create a tar file for each subfolder. Suppose I need to restore one special files. To easily find the containing archive, I want to save its name.  

But the basic question is simple: how can I append the same string to each line?

Comment: And doesn't my answer work for you? Although I still don't understand why you would do this. Just keep a list of files in `currentdir` and keep the tar in the same dir. Or name the `contents.list` as `tarName.list`. Or just use `tar -t` to list the contents of the tar file. But as you wish.

Comment: It works, thank You again!
The data must be stored in a long-term archive (tape drive) and deleted from our server. The admin recommends max. 16GB files for tape robots. If I understand it correctly, I first have to read the whole archive from the tape and assemble it from 16GB parts before I could do `tar -t`. Therefore, I would like to have a directory file that shows where a certain file or folder is contained.

Comment: I would just make one tar per directory, and add a `.contents` file to each directory. That way, you would have `dirnName.tar` and `dirName.contents` and you wouldn't need to have the dirName repeated on every line which just increases file size for no benefit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a while loop for this will be very slow. If all you want is to add a static string to the end of each line, use `sed` instead:

```
du --all | sed 's/$/ myArchive.tar/'
```

Or, if you want to have the archive name in a variable (e.g. `$i`):

```
du --all | sed "s/$/ $i/"
```

`s/old/new/` is sed's replacement operator and will replace the first occurrence of `old` with `new`. The symbol `$` matches the end of the line, so `s/$/foo/` will just add `foo` to the end of each line.

Comment: Thank!  `du --all | sed 's/$/"   myArchive.tar"/'` is exactly that I want!
sed and awk are still on my have to learn list :-)

Comment: @AlexK ah, OK. Answer updated. Sorry, I thought you wanted it at the beginning.

Comment: I should write append...

Answer (score 1):

Typically, for cases where I want to perform an operation on a list of inputs, especially if that operation is pretty straightforward, I'd opt for using `xargs`; in this case, I'd go with something like this:

```
du --all currentdir | xargs -I{} echo "{} mytar" >> contents.list
```

`xargs` has generally been shown to be pretty performant, and I think it's more readable (doesn't require remembering the significance of various regex symbols, which can vary between implementations and aren't always intuitive.)

Comment: Welcome, this is slower than the OP's while, at least `time` says so. OP's: `real    0m0,015s`, your solution: `real    0m0,087s`. But I don't know if the difference would be in favour of `xargs` with huge files.

Comment: It works too! Thank you. I suppose xargs would improve performance in case of paralellisation. du use probably only one thread. Sorry, can't upvote You due to own low reputation.

Comment: @AlexK I'll upvote for you :)

Comment: Using `printf` instead of `echo` is more performant.

Answer (score 0):

Using `du` for this is the wrong approach.  Instead, once you've created your tar files, just use `tar tv` to list their contents.  e.g.

```
for f in *.tar.gz; do
  tar tvfz "$f" > "$f.list"
done
```

This will create a .list file for each tar.gz file.  If you then want to create a consolidated list, you could use `grep`.  e.g.

```
grep -H . *.tar.gz.list > contents.list
```

The pattern `.` matches anything and the `-H` option tells grep to prefix its output with the filename and a colon even if there's only one input filename (by default, grep only does that if there are multiple input files)

Comment: Thank You @cas. Normally I would complete agree with you.   I  have to split the archive into 16GB parts, because that is best for the tape robot. `tar -czpv "$archFile" "$quellDir" 
| split -d -a 5 -b $SplitBlockSize - "$archiveDir/$(basename $quellDir).tar.gz"  ` I split the archive when I create it. I assume `tar -t` is not possible in this case. My situation is: TBs of data and actually not enough space on the storage server to create a large tar and then split it.

Comment: In that case, just use `find . -ls` or `ls -lR` to generate `contents.list`.